# How many of the n! permutations π from set N to N satisfy min(π(A)) = min(π(B))

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Given a set of elements $N = \{1, 2,\ldots, n\}$ and two arbitrary subsets $A\subseteq N$ and $B\subseteq N$, how many of the $n!$ permutations π from $N$ to $N$ satisfy min(π$(A)$) = min(π$(B)$), where min(S) is the smallest integer in the set of integers S, and π(S) is the set of integers obtained by applying permutation π to each element of S?

I find it difficult to approach this problem.

First I assume $n =3$, so $N=\{1,2,3\}$.

I consider $A=\{1,2\}$ and $B = \{2,3\}$.

Then apply π$(A)$, which i have doubt how to form set of integers.

Suppose π$(A)= \{1,2\}$ and π$(B)=\{1,2,3\}$.

I don't get it how to apply min(π$(A)$)=min(π$(B)$).

The options to the question are

(A) $(n - |A ∪ B|) |A| |B| $

(B) $(|A|^2+|B|^2)n^2$

(C) $n!(|A∩B|/|A∪B|)$

(D) $(|A∩B|)^2/(n/|A∪B|)$

Comment: Note that $A \cap B = \emptyset$ implies that $\pi (A) \cap \pi(B) = \emptyset$, so they cannot have the same minimum. In particular answers (A) and (B) cannot be correct.

Comment: Note that $A \cap B = \emptyset$ implies that $\pi (A) \cap \pi(B) = \emptyset$, so they cannot have the same minimum. In particular answers (A) and (B) cannot be correct. Then you can also say that (D) is not correct. In fact, let $A=\{1\}$ and $B = \{ 1, \dots, n\}$. Then formula (D) gives you only one permutation, but clearly every permutation fixing $1$ is good, so the answer cannot be (D). This means that the correct answer must be (C) (assuming there is a correct answer among the four).

Answer (score 3):

I will use $\rho$ rather than $\pi$ to represent an arbitrary permutation.

If $\text{min}(\rho(A)) = \text{min}(\rho(B))$, say $y = \rho(x)$ is the common minimum.  Since the permutation $\rho$ is a 1-to-1 mapping of $N$, it follows that $x \in A\cap B$.  So the intersection $C = A\cap B$ cannot be empty for this to happen.

The desired outcome is that $y = \rho(x) \in \rho(A\cap B)$ is the minimum of $\rho(A\cup B)$, if the minimums of $\rho(A)$ and $\rho(B)$ are to be the same.

The permutation $\rho$ must send $A\cup B$ to any equal-sized subset of $N$, and the desired outcome depends only on whether the least element of $\rho(A\cup B)$ belongs to $\rho(A\cap B)$.  Considering all possible permutations, the fraction of them that meet this condition is simply $|\rho(A\cap B)|/|\rho(A\cup B)|$.  It follows from the 1-to-1 mapping that this fraction is also $|A\cap B|/|A\cup B|$, and the total number is given by multiplying by $n!$:

$$ n! \frac{|A\cap B|}{|A\cup B|} $$

This agrees with one of your multiple choice answers.

To use your example of $N=\{1,2,3\}$ with $A=\{1,2\}$ and $B=\{2,3\}$, we see that a  permutation can act on $N=A\cup B$ in six ways.  Of these, one-third will map $2 \in A\cap B$ to the minimum position.  Therefore the total number of permutations such that $\text{min}(\rho(A)) = \text{min}(\rho(B))$ is six times one-third:

$$ 3! \frac{|A\cap B|}{|A\cup B|} = 6 \cdot \frac{1}{3} = 2 $$

Comment: Nice. How would you prove that "the fraction of them that meet this condition is simply $|\rho(A\cap B)|/|\rho(A\cup B)|$"?.

I would say that the probability for a single permutation is  $|\rho(A\cap B)|/|\rho(A\cup B)|$  and that every permutation is equally random.

Anyway, how to explain it to a beginner ? @hardmath

Comment: To a beginner I think the key insight is seeing that whether $\min(\rho(A))=\min(\rho(B))$ holds depends only on whether $\min(\rho(A\cap B)) = \min(\rho(A\cup B))$.  In effect you are reducing to the case $A \subset B$.  The Venn diagram is now easier to draw and look at!  If I find time, I'll draw such a picture and add to my Answer.

Answer (score 0):

The number of permutations you are after is $\sum_{i\in N}|\{ \,\pi\mid \min(\pi(A))=i=\min(\pi(B))\,\}|$. You can compute each of the terms in that summation fairly easily.

Comment: Sorry sir , I don't get the term π(A) and π(B) . Can u please elaborate with an example .